# DHCP on commit script not running

Tags: scripts, dhcp

So I have a basic DHCP set up -

```
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
option routers 192.168.0.254;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
range 192.168.0.15 192.168.0.253;
        on commit {
                execute("/home/user/script");
        }
}
```

I feel like a total idiot asking, but any idea why the script might not be running?  The script works and behaves as expected.  Permissions are set at 777 right now just for troubleshooting.  Still, when I go into the DHCP log, it says that the script failed to execute with a permission denied error code of 32512.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats the output of `namei -m /home/user/script` ?

Comment: -rwxrwxrwx script - i.e. 777

Comment: give the full output of `namei -m /home/user/script`

Comment: f: /etc/dhcp/log_access
 drwxr-xr-x /
 drwxr-xr-x etc
 drwxr-xr-x dhcp
 -rwxrwxrwx log_access

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the right permission (read+execute) on the directory containing the executable  too.

If you have a script named `script.sh` in `/home/foo/` and it has the octal permission of 775.

Now if you want to run the script as a different user e.g. `bar`, then `bar` needs to have read and execute permission on `/`, `/home` and `/home/foo` directories otherwise `bar` will get a permission denied message regardless of the permission of `/home/foo/script.sh`.